# How can I factory reset a European Huawei phone in China without access to Google?

Tags: factory-reset, google-account, boot-loop

Well, as you can see in the title......I am having a hard time in China. :)
My phone is from Spain and I had to factory reset it (it got soft-bricked...just on its own. Weirdest thing ever). It is a Huawei P8 Lite 2017 with literally no support. Whatever is on the internet (PC suite) can't be used because it says it is not a supported phone.

**Is there a way to continue the factory reset without the Google service? It is blocked here.**

This is the screen where I am stuck atm:

[image: FRP]

Comment: You could find a PC with access to the outer web (e.g. with VPN) and use a proxy software on it so that all other devices in the same network can use the PC as proxy and get through. Not sure if you're willing to take the complications though.

Comment: Short answer... You cant. Long answer, see Andy's comment.

Comment: @AndyYan I am willing to do that and I have a PC with VPN on it, but I have no clue how to do such thing. Do you have a walkthrough or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reach Google and proceed with the next steps, you need to set up a PC that's capable of penetrating through *that wall* (e.g. with VPN), and make it a proxy server on the local network for your phone to use. Here's the way I do it:

1. On your PC, install Privoxy and let it through your firewall (if exists)
2. Go to its installation directory and open `config.txt`. You might need to open it with administrator privilege to be able to save it later.
3. Search for "listen-address" and you should get something like this:

   > listen-address  127.0.0.1:8118

   It should be right above the chapter "4.2 toggle" and not have a "#" before it. Edit it to:

   > listen-address  0.0.0.0:8118

   Now save the file.
4. Determine the LAN IP of your PC, usually by running `ipconfig` in the Command Prompt. Suppose it's `192.168.0.1`.
5. Fire up Privoxy and connect to the VPN you use. Now your PC is ready; move on to the phone.
6. While in Setup Wizard, connect your phone to the same network as your PC. If you have already connected to the network, make the phone forget it and set it up from scratch. When entering setup details, check Advanced Options, then choose "Manual" for Proxy. Enter the IP and port you got previously. It should look like this:

   [image]

   Proceed to connect.

Your phone should now use your PC as a proxy, and therefore should be able to reach Google. Follow the on-screen guidance afterwards.

Comment: I like your answer..although I used the tutorial on the VPN express wbsite to create a virtual network on the windows side of my laptop and updated the phone via that. Cheers Andy.

Comment: Interesting, let me try Privoxy.