# How to skip Checking network when first setting up the device?

Tags: hard-reset

Since Google is blocked in China and a few other countries, the Checking network screen will stuck forever. Is there a way to skip this step?

Comment: Apparently, from the tag you've used "hard-reset", you've restored your device to factory settings and haven't un-ticked the options "Backup my data" & "Automatic Restore", search with the keywords FRP Bypass for your device.

Comment: Refer to [this answer of mine](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173205/how-can-i-factory-reset-a-european-huawei-phone-in-china-without-access-to-googl/173237#173237) to set up a PC as a proxy server and connect the device to the proxy so it can pass the phase normally. What Abdelhafid said is true to an extent though - if setup wizard does not allow skipping network check, then the device likely has a Google account and you will need a FRP bypass.

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui how would I install an APK if it doesn't let me go into the system?

Comment: @AndyYan yes I've tried, yet I cannot get it work somehow. I don't think the phone recognizes the proxy setting...

Comment: @AeroWindwalker That's the point of FRP bypassing procedures - there's often a device/version-specific way that allows you to temporarily access a part of the OS so you can install and run APKs. As for the proxy step, well if your PC isn't capable of penetrating the lockdown itself then the proxy will be useless.

Comment: @AndyYan turns out FRP will ignore the proxy setting, I had to create a router wide tunnel instead of proxy to connect to Google.

Comment: That's kinda weird, I've done a FRP bypass myself just last month and the Samsung tablet I had hands on respected the proxy setting nicely. Good thing that you figured it out in the end though.

Comment: @AndyYan probably your Android version is not the same. Mine is 7.0.

Comment: @ AndyYan now even the router wide proxy setting doesn't work. I simply got a greyed out next button before going to "Checking network."